# Disable days datepicker based on selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm having a problem disabling days of the week in the jQuery datepicker based on selected dropdown.

Below is my HTML and javascript code:

```html
<script>
    $("#dates").datepicker({
        minDate: 0
    });
</script>
```

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , id = "dates" } })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dayOff,
    new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value="0" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Monday", Value="1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Tuesday",Value= "2" },
    }, 
    new { @class = "form-control", onchange="test()", id ="drop1" })
```

I have a dropdownlist that a user can select the days of the week and a textbox that will show the calendar.

What I want is for example a user select Monday, all mondays on the calendar will be disabled.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap datepicker then you can use the following code snippet to disable the days on change event of the Drop down list.
(Bootstrap date picker demo: https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)

```
var disableDaysArray= [3];
$('#dates').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekDisabled',disableDaysArray);
```

Refer the documentation for more details. 
URL: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html